# Floating point evaluation order in C

Tags: c

I am using Code::Blocks 10.05 on Windows 7.

I have compiled the following program,

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
 float f=1.5;
 printf("%f\n",(f-1)*1/2);
 return 0;
}
```

The output was **0.250000**.
I understand it as follows,

Since `f` is a float `(f-1)` returns a float value of **0.500000** and the whole expression is upgraded to floating point arithmetic and hence **1/2** is also treated as float to get **0.500000** and hence the result.

Also the following statement,

```
 float f=1.5;
 printf("%f\n",1/2*(f-1));
```

gave **0.000000** as answer. 
Here the expression `1/2` performed integer division. Here I expected `(f-1)` to be evaluated first and the whole expression to be upgraded to floating point arithmetic.

Here again I thought since the Polish notation is,

```
* / 1 2 - f 1
```

division is the first operation performed and hence the result.
Am I correct about this assumption?

Finally the following statement defies all the logic,

```
 float f=1.5;
 printf("%f\n",(f-1)*(1/2));
```

The output is **0.000000**, 
But here the Polish notation is,

```
* - f 1 / 1 2
```

So `(f-1)` ought to be evaluated first and hence the whole expression upgrades to floating
point arithmetic and the output should be **0.250000**.

Where did I go wrong?
Does this have something to do with evaluation order of the operator *?
Is the expression ambiguous in C?

Comment: The evaluation order doesn't change just because there are floating point values or variables involved. [Operator precedence and associativity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) is always the same.

Comment: "hence 1/2" -- There's no such expression in the first case. " Here I expected (f-1) to be evaluated first and the whole expression to be upgraded to floating point arithmetic." -- I can't imagine why. "Finally the following statement defies all the logic" -- No, it makes perfect sense. "the whole expression upgrades to floating point arithmetic" -- where do you get this weird idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since f is a float (f-1) returns a float value of 0.500000 and the whole expression is upgraded to floating point arithmetic

No, where did you get that misinformation from? Promotion to floating-point only applies to the one operator of which either operand is a floating-point number. `1/2` is **not** treated as a floating-point expression -- as such, it's not even evaluated. Since multiplication and division have the same precedence and are left-associative,

```
(f - 1) * 1 / 2
```

is evaluated as

```
((f - 1) * 1) / 2)
```

And there, `1` is promoted to `float` (at least), and then because `((f - 1) * 1)` is floating-point as well, then the other operand of the division, `2` is also promoted to `float` (or a higher precision FP number, depending on what the compiler wants).

> Here I expected (f-1) to be evaluated first and the whole expression to be upgraded to floating point arithmetic.

No, that's an incorrect expectation, as I just explained. It's **not** the full expression that is subject to conversion to floating-point. It's *only* the other immediate operand of the operator of which the one operand is a `float`. Hence in the expression:

```
(f - 1) * (1 / 2)
```

`f - 1` is a `float`. `1 / 2` is an integer, it is zero, and then the integer zero is promoted to `float` because the other operand of `*` is a `float`. The operands of `/`, however, are integers, so the division is evaluated according to the rules of integer arithmetic.

Comment: Awesome answer, very detailed. You got my +1 for that.

Comment: "1 is promoted to float (at least)"  No, it is promoted to `float`, period. The compiler might use the same precision for `float` and `double` but that's another story.

Answer (score 2):

`*` and `/` have the same precedence, so `(f-1)*1/2` is equivalent to `((f-1)*1)/2`, not what you think it is.

While `1/2*(f-1)` is equivalent to `(1/2)*(f-1)` in which `1/2` has the value of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the paranthesis: `(1/2)` you only get a big zero (the result of 1/2) upgraded to a float. Hence the zero result.

Answer (score 0):

`(1/2)` is treated as integer and results zero. Multiplication by zero leads result which is also zero.

Answer (score -1):

The expression is evaluated  from left to right:

- The expression `f` is a `float`.
- In the expression `f - 1` both operands are promoted to `double`, the value is `0.5`. Call the expression `E1`.
- Same for `(f - 1) * 1`, which is `E1 * 1`, both operands are promoted to `double` and the value of the expression is`0.5`. Call the expression `E2`.
- Same for `(f - 1) * 1 / 2`, which is `E2 / 2`, both operands are promoted to `double` and the value of th eexpression is `0.25`.

Comment: More accurately, the expression is _parsed_ left to right because of operator associativity. But the order of evaluation between the sub-expressions `f-1`, `1` and `2` is unspecified. Doesn't matter in this case, but it might matter in another case.

Comment: "In the expression f - 1 both operands are promoted to double"  No, `f` is already `float` and `1` is promoted to `float`, as per "the usual arithmetic conversions". The only promotion to `double` that occurs here is when the whole expression is done and the resulting `float` is passed to `printf`.